# How to check if a namespace is active

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm using the following command to check if the namespace is active

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=items.status.phase=Active namespace/mynamespace --timeout=2s
```

This always returns "error: timed out waiting for the condition on namespaces/mynamespace" although the namespace is active.
Is there a correct way to wait for the namespace to be active?  This script is part of a job to check the namespace is active after a AKS cluster restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To date `status` is not a recognized `condition`. Try:

`while ! [ "$(kubectl get ns <change to your namespace> -o jsonpath='{.status.phase}')" == "Active" ]; do echo 'Waiting for namespace to come online. CTRL-C to exit.'; sleep 1; done`

Answer (score 1):

You can wait on an arbitrary jsonpath:

```bash
kubectl wait --for jsonpath='{.status.phase}=Active' --timeout=5s namespace/default
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timeout_value=3
starttime=$(date +%s)
while [ $(( $(date +%s) - $timeout_value )) -lt $starttime ]; do
     status=$(kubectl get ns mynamespace -o jsonpath='{.status.phase}')
     status=${status:-"X"}
     echo $status
     if [ "$status" == "Active" ];then
        echo " test"
        break
     fi
done
```

Modified @gohm'c answer to include a timeout value of 3 seconds.